# Powermockito - cannot mock/spy a system class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock a static method in the `java.nio.file.Files` class like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Files.class})
public class MockStaticTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        Path absolutePath = Paths.get("AB", "CD", "EF");
        mockStatic(Files.class);
        when(Files.createDirectories(absolutePath)).thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

When I execute the test class, I get this exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.nio.file.Files
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class

    at MockStaticTest.test(MockStaticTest.java:22)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

However, if I try to mock any other final class, it works without any issues, for ex:

```
import io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Files.class, NettyChannelBuilder.class})
public class MockStaticTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        Path absolutePath = Paths.get("AB", "CD", "EF");
//        mockStatic(Files.class);
        mockStatic(NettyChannelBuilder.class);
//        when(Files.createDirectories(absolutePath)).thenReturn(null);
        when(NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("", 0)).thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me out with this ? Why the `Files` class is throwing a mock exception ?

Maven dependencies:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.28.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Literally copying your example code and running it as unittest does not give me any errors.

Comment: woow...did you copy the one which has ` when(Files.createDirectories(absolutePath)).thenReturn(null);`. Thank you for looking into it

Comment: checked on somebody else's machine and he is also getting the same error.

Comment: While that does not solve your issue, take a look at the [`Mocking system classes`](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System#example) section in the powermock docu. That works in combination with `mockito-core 2.26.0`. You should file a bugreport in their issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatch between Mockito and PowerMock versions. Check [Powermock documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions) for versions alignment.

Here is a maven setup i used to reproduce the problem (brakes on Files, works fine with NettyChannelBuilder):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Both classes work if i switch to Mockito 2.10.0:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: then would it work for other static classes ? I tried mocking using PowerMock other final classes and final static methods which worked without any issues. I am facing an issue with this particular class. But I appreciate your comment and would update the version shortly

Comment: This seems strange indeed, but it works like that. I will update answer with maven versions i used to reproduce it and the one that is working, maybe it will help You.

Comment: Its still working with a `mockito` version below `2.27.0`. Note that `powermock 2.0.2` was build against `2.23.0`, after that some things apparently broke.